# Send and receive stuff? What to use in receiving in-from or in-to

Tags: prepositions

hope you can help me.

I am not sure what should I use (or what is actually correct to use). I want to say that "I am sending stuff from one place to another" and at the same time "I am receiving stuff from other places to one specific place".
Specifically, I want to say that I am sending data from one processor to another, and receiving data from other processors to one particular processor. I am doing a Table where I am presenting the "amount" of data I am sending and receiving. Something like this

```
Sent           Sent stuff       Received     Received stuff
From 1 to 2       X Mb        In 1 from 2        X Mb
From 1 to 3       X Mb        In 1 from 3        X Mb
From 1 to 4       X Mb        In 1 from 4        X Mb
From 2 to 1       X Mb        In 2 from 1        X Mb
From 2 to 3       X Mb        In 2 from 3        X Mb
From 2 to 4       X Mb        In 2 from 4        X Mb
```

But I am not sure whether I should use "In # from #" or "In # to #" in the  "Received" column.

Comment: You could say *"**Into** 1 from 2"*, if you're thinking of it as "finishing a sentence" which is started in the table column header, eg "Sent from 1 to 2" and "Received into 1, from 2".

Comment: If the source and destination are being characterized primarily as objects or actors, then you could say received "***by*** 1 from 2".  In fact, you could use a similar construction to describe the sends: "by 1 to 2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stuff is sent *by* someone (A) *from* somewhere (A') *to* somewhere else (B') where it's received *by* someone else (B).

So stuff is received *at* B' having been sent *from* A' (locations).

Or stuff is received *by* B having been sent *by* A (participants).

(You could also say that stuff is sent *from* A or *to* B as participants, but that's still looking at A and B as locations, in that the package departed from A in some sense and arrived at B - mixed usage).

--

That means your headings can be *Sent from x to y* and *Received at y from x*.

If you consider that the processors are doing the sending, then you could shift to *Sent by x to y* and *Received by y sent by x* (clumsy) or *Received by y from x* (clearer).

Comment: Thus, considering that processors are _participants_ , or _actors_ as @PellMel metioned, it may be right to change the content in the column "Sent" by "by # to #" and in the column "Received" by "by # from #".

Comment: @PePeLoTe Yes - answer edited for clarity and to incorporate this.